# C formatted string - How to add leading zeros to string value using sprintf?

Tags: c, printf, string-formatting

I want to add zeroes at the starting of a string. I am using format specifier.
My input string is `hello`
I want output as `000hello`.

I know how to do this for integer.

```
int main()
{
    int i=232;
    char str[21];
    sprintf(str,"%08d",i);

    printf("%s",str);

    return 0;
}
```

> OUTPUT will be -- 00000232

If I do the same for string.

```
 int main()
    {
        char i[]="hello";
        char str[21];
        sprintf(str,"%08s",i);

        printf("%s",str);

        return 0;
    }
```

> OUTPUT will be -    hello (with 3 leading space)

Why it is giving space in case of string and zero in case of integer?

Comment: printf("000000%s", helloStr)

Comment: What I would do is have an array, and set all of the elements to '0', except the last for the null terminator. Then Copy your string in at the appropriate place (hint: use `strlen`) and print that. Alternatively, have a loop that prints the right number of '0's, then prints the string.

Comment: *I am using format specifier. My input string is "hello"*. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Show the input, the expected output, and the actual output, **in the question**.

Comment: Will you always have at least one leading zero?

Comment: I see no attempts to solve this problem yourself.

Answer (score 2):

> How to add leading zeros to string value using sprintf?

Use `"%0*d%s"` to prepend zeros.

`"%0*d"` --> `0` min width of zeros, `*` derived width from the argument list, `d` print an `int`.

An exception is needed when the *string* needs no zeros up front.

```
void PrependZeros(char *dest, const char *src, unsigned width) {
  size_t len = strlen(src);
  if (len >= width) strcpy(dest, src);
  else sprintf(dest, "%0*d%s", (int) (width - len), 0, src);
}
```

---

Yet I do not think `sprintf()` is the right tool for the job and would code as below.

```
// prepend "0" as needed resulting in a string of _minimal_ width.
void PrependZeros(char *dest, const char *src, unsigned minimal_width) {
  size_t len = strlen(src);
  size_t zeros = (len > minimal_width) ? 0 : minimal_width - len;
  memset(dest, '0', zeros);
  strcpy(dest + zeros, src);
}
```

---

```
void testw(const char *src, unsigned width) {
  char dest[100];
  PrependZeros(dest, src, width);
  printf("%u <%s>\n", width, dest);
}

int main() {
  for (unsigned w = 0; w < 10; w++)
    testw("Hello", w);
  for (unsigned w = 0; w < 2; w++)
    testw("", w);
}
```

Output

```
0 <Hello>
1 <Hello>
2 <Hello>
3 <Hello>
4 <Hello>
5 <Hello>
6 <0Hello>
7 <00Hello>
8 <000Hello>
9 <0000Hello>
0 <>
1 <0>
```

Comment: The second version writes more than `width` in some cases (this should at least be noted in header comments, if not tested for)

Comment: @M.M Fair enough.  Advanced issue. Could use `void PrependZeros(char * restrict dest, const char * restrict src, unsigned minimal_width) {` to emphasize src and dest should not overlap.

Answer (score -1):

```
void left_fill_zeros(char* dest, const char* str, int length)
{
    sprintf(dest, "%.*d%s", (int)(length-strlen(str)), 0, str);
}

int main(void)
{
    char output[256];
    left_fill_zeros(output, "Hello", 10);
    puts(output);

    // Total length will be 10 chars
    // Output will be: "00000Hello"
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, on review, my answer only varies a bit to cope with small widths and does some error checking.  Too bad this answer's 2 DV did not also include some detail as to its weakness.   It certainly is at least  good starting point.

Comment: I didn't vote, but your code will start a fire if `length < strlen(str)`