# How do I pad an array with leading zeroes?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I'm new to C++, and trying to pad a character array with leading zeroes. I've seen answers of printing with padded zeroes, but I'd like to pad the array directly.

In this case, I have an array of size `[20]`. So if I input `123456789`, the number will be padded with 11 zeroes and `00000000000123456789` will be printed. Or if input is 1, then 19 leading zeroes will be appended and `00000000000000000001` is printed.

```
char input[20];

int main () {
  cout << "Enter a number - ";
  cin >> input; // Eg. "12"
  //*code here*
  printf("%s\n", input); // Prints "00000000000000000012"
```

There should be an easy way to do this but I just can't find it. The code I've tried so far goes something like this...

```
for (int i = 0; i < number_of_zeroes; i++) { //pad with zeroes
input[i] = '0';
```

But this just overwrites the input with zeroes. I'd like to insert zeroes instead.

Comment: What did you try to solve it?

Comment: C or C++? Make up your mind.

Comment: Then use std::string.

Comment: For the purposes of what I want to use the code for, I'd rather stick to the code format above.

Comment: @Osiris I've tried using a for loop to append zeroes to the array given the string length, but it appears quite messy. I was wondering if I could get some more ideas here since I'm new to programming in C++

Comment: FWIW `std::string` doesn't really have any disadvantage to using `char[20]`. If you feel you mustn't use `std::string`, then I think you should [edit] your question to talk about why, since the answer might be you misjudged it. `std::string` can make many things far easier, and what would take you several lines of unreadable code with `char[]` would be very easy to read and write in `std::string`

Comment: Show us the code you have written so far and we can help you find the problems. For now the question looks a bit like a pure code writing request.

Comment: @Osiris Forgive me, I'm not used to posting questions on here. I'll update my question with your suggestions ><

Comment: For the simpler way, you need to use predefined functions
Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43354488/c-formatted-string-how-to-add-leading-zeros-to-string-value-using-sprintf)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the link Chetan Tamboli provided I was able to solve my own question.

```
char input[20];
char newinput[20];

int main () {
  cout << "Enter a number - ";
  cin >> input;
  sprintf(newinput,"%020s",input);
  printf("%s\n",newinput);

}
```

Thank you to everyone that helped! I really appreciate it.

Comment: This causes undefined behaviour; the `0` printf format flag is only valid for numeric conversions.  If it appears to work for you it's either an accident or a non-standard extension that your system implements.

Comment: I see, how would you improve this answer then? It seems to work fine for me.

Comment: You could use the code suggested by "chux" in the answer to the other question